# Can anyone explain how this function is works in express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, error-handling

Express Error Handling:  https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Defining a default error-handling middleware function :

```js
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})
```

According to the docs

> If you pass an error to next() and you do not handle it in a custom error handler, it will be handled by the built-in error handler; the error will be written to the client with the stack trace.

I understand that **for errors returned from asynchronous functions invoked by route handlers and middleware, I must pass them to the `next(err)` function, where Express will catch and process them in the default error-handling middleware function like the one shown in the above code**.

But then I came across this code :

```js
const catchAsync = fn =>  {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
    }
}

let response = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const results = await some_promise();
    res.json({
        results
    })
})
```

*`some_promise()` is an API call that returns a `Promise`*

Can anyone explain how this code processes an error. If possible please provide a simplified version without the use of `catchAsync` function.

Comment: _"...without the use of `catchAsync` function."_ - But that's where the error handling happens: `.catch(next)`

Comment: @Andreas , I get that but can we use a `Try` - `catch` for _response_ and call `next(err)` inside the `catch` block? Will that work?

Comment: @RizulBhardwaj Yes you could also do that

Comment: @Bergi Okay thanks I got it now  :-)